# How to extract more than one field value from native query in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, native-sql

In the Hibernate, the former programmer implemented native query like this.

```
query = "select id from employee";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString).addScalar(scalarName, StringType.INSTANCE);
return query.list();
```

However, I would like to add one more field into query like

```
query = "select id, dept from employee";
```

If I do not add any code, it does return only id not including dept. 
I need multiple fields' value. I tried some references like http://www.journaldev.com/3422/hibernate-native-sql-query-example
but still I can't fiture it out, does anybody have a solution for this quickly? :) 
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
query = "select id, dept from employee";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
return query.list();
```

Where `query.list();` returns a list of `Object[]` and Object[0] ==> the id and Object[1] is the value of dept

Comment: I made it, i had to solve this quickly, so could not do enough research. anyway, it was so helpful. thank you so much!

Comment: @AnnaLee You are welcome. If it is helpful, feeel free to upvote and/or accept the answer

Comment: @AnnaLee I have upvoted the question but you have not even accepted the answer. It is wrong to not accept a correct answer - especially when you agree that it is correct.